# How the Window.Activated event is triggerred?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using a wpf application where application sturcture is like

1. Exe1 launches Exe2 using WaitForExit method.
2. Then Exe2's main Window1 launches Window2 with a owner window of Window1.
3. And finally Window1 launches a new external Exe3 using System.Diagnostics.Process.

Normally when i close an Exe3, Windows2 is getting activated which is an ideal case.
But at some cases when i close External Exe3, Exe1  is getting activated. So the Exe2 is going backward which is an issue.

Kindly provide your inputs why the Exe1 is stealing the focus.
Thanks in advance for your valuable answers.

Comment: Did you mean Window1 is getting activated sometimes when you close Exe2?

Comment: Can you please specify which of these exes you're the author of/can modify?

Comment: Hi SpaceghostAli, Exe1 is getting activated when i close Exe3.

Comment: Hi Damien, I can modify only Exe2.

Answer (score 0):

When closing Windows the next `Window` to be activated depends on the last `Window` that was active before it. If you hit Alt Tab you'll see the ordering but if you need a specific `Window` to always get activated after closing another try passing a reference to that `Window` so you can call the `Activate` method when the first `Window` is closing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. By using Window.Activate() method, it is working fine. But in my error case Window2 was active before launching Exe3, but after closing Exe3 Window2 is not getting the Activate command.